# SqlAlchemy ORM concurrent updates

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, sqlalchemy, transaction-isolation

I am trying to understand how I can prevent concurrent updates from breaking my application. Imagine the following example

```
Bob retrieves Post#1
Alice retrieves Post#1
Bob modifies and saves Post#1
Alice modifies and saves Post#1
```

Now Bobs changes have been overwritten because Alice never saw that Bob had changed anything. This is a very common issue among web applications, since many users may work on the same data at the same time.

This issue is not restricted to simple cases like the ones above. Bob might touch several database tables before committing the transaction.

So how to prevent this? One thing I can think of is using some hashes on the rows. Each time a `Post` is updated, it will get a new uuid4 stored with it. So when Alice tries to modify it, she needs to send the hash that she got when reading the post in the first place:

```
GET /posts/1
response: {
    'text': 'Old post',
    '_hash': 'cef999ea-cffd-4ef8-b219-1ee905bbdbea'
}
POST /posts/1
{
    'text': 'New text, that I just wrote',
    '_hash': 'cef999ea-cffd-4ef8-b219-1ee905bbdbea'
}
```

Now, the application should have some way to only update the database row if the hash is the same as what is currently stored

```
UPDATE table SET (...) WHERE pk=1 AND _hash='cef999ea-cffd-4ef8-b219-1ee905bbdbea'
```

In this case, Alice would get an error, because the row she wants to update does not exist, because Bob's update changed the hash. The application layer would then be able to help Alice consolidate the two updates (hers and bob's).

Is this possible with the sql alchemy orm? I assume when I commit the transaction, it will update the row `WHERE pk=1`. How would I make it also use the hash?

Is this method feasible? If the action touches many tables, a lot of hashes need to be checked and handled, and that might get pretty messy. What other solutions could I use? Database row locking has a lot of pitfalls, which are hard to escape.

Comment: In my experience, concurrency problems like you are describing are rarely an issue. But yes sometimes they are. Some years ago I implemented a solution based on [optimistic control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control). I don't quite recall all the details, but it did work, and it was far simpler than your description; anyhow yours should work as well. `SQLAlchemy` has no support I think. Anyway it is not difficult to implement. Also, [this thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=301887) explains several approaches, not all of them "orthodox". Hope it helps.

Comment: Your comment is definitely helpful. I hadn't heard of OCC before. Led me to this article which explains in pretty understandable english: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-read-modify-write-cycles/